# AJAX request return 403 (Forbidden) error

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Ajax request to localhost return 403 error. However, when  I change the controller requestMethod to GET and open the request "url" on the browser, it displays the json data returned from server.I wish to use the data to populate a dropdown list. Please, help. I'm using spring security 4.0 with spring MVC frame work. CSRF is not disable. Also, the url is secured in spring.

I have checked related questions here but didn't see a solution that helps me.

Comment: Add the code that is causing the error, please.

Comment: @J.Titus It didn't display any error at level of script or spring/Java code. I checked at the browser console and saw the request status as forbiden. Then I opened the request url on browser and saw that data was returned from server normally.   http://localhost:8080/myapp/getCats

Comment: I'm talking about the 403 error. What does your AJAX call look like?

Comment: The fact that you can go to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/getCategories` in the browser and get the data tells me that the `GET` request is working. Why do you have it set up as `POST` in your AJAX request?

Comment: @EdwardoS silly question but is your controller accepting POST request and are you also sending through CSRF with your ajax post call? Show us your controller code as well please

Comment: I was thinking I may later add some parameters to the request, and so secure them

Comment: @Aeseir Sorry if question is not understandable. I intended sending the request through CSRF. Is it possible? See my controller code above. Thanks

Comment: No it doesn't make sense, also you removed the code making the question even more difficult to troubleshoot. Your answer doesn't relate to the original problem also. So this is now very confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are receiving a 403 because of one of these reasons:

- Your controller is not accepting POST call
- You are not submitting a CSRF with your ajax post call
- You are making an incorrect call from your ajax

For each of the above:

- Ensure your controller accepts POST call
- Ensure your ajax POST calls are also submitting CSRF
- Ensure you use the correct type of call depending on the requirements (data retrieval should be GET, creation should be POST, modification should be PUT and removal should be DELETE, check out the restful guidelines for best practice [enter link description here](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)

The answer you provided doesn't help you understand what your problem is thus you will face more of these types of issues down the track which will be difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for your enlightenment. It's quite helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out:
I changed the request methods of both AJAX call and its controller from POST to GET and obtain 200 - OK  status for request. Also, when I open the AJAX request "URL" on the browser on which I'm logged in on my web app, it displays JSON data. However, when I open on a browser on which I'm not logged in, Spring security requests my login -  Perfect I guess!.

Please is this action OK from a security standpoint?

Comment: Depending on your usage, i'll give you an answer that you can base your solution going down the track, coz i can forsee problems in your code